# How to get a "classical" globe projection

Tags: coordinate-system

I have a shapefile of the world continents in EPSG 4326.

To what reference system do I have to reproject my file to get a projecting like this globe below?[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This family of projection is called *azimuthal orthographic* (all rays from globe to flat map are parallel). You can define the Lat/long coordinates of the center of the projection to choose the visible hemisphere.

There is no EPSG code from what I know, but here is the PROJ.4 definition.

```
+proj=ortho +lat_0=Latitude at projection center 
            +lon_0=Longitude at projection center
            +x_0=False Easting
            +y_0=False Northing
```

[image: example with lat = 0 and long = -41]

Comment: If you use a shapefile, you might have to clip it to the visible half of the globe, as I explained here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70207/where-did-the-polygons-go-after-projecting-a-map-in-qgis

Answer (score 1):

A variation (on the already suggested azimuthal *orthographic* projection) would be to use an azimuthal *perspective* projection, similar to what's used in Google Earth. This mimics what you'd see looking at a real globe via the lens of the eyes or camera, but covering a little less than a "full" hemisphere. I don't know the parameters to use, but you'd need to experiment with different altitudes and scales to get close to your given sketch map.

Answer (score 0):

My web-based Globus Map Projector can also do that for you. Go here: https://www.winski.net/?page_id=12, and choose the full version of the projector. From there you can simply select your *project to* to *ortographic*.

[image]