# Using gdalwarp for warping Space View Perspective or Orthographic tiff?

Tags: coordinate-system, gdalwarp

i need to warp an image with a Space View Perspective or Orthographic project. What is the parameter for the gdalwarp -s_srs "+proj=???? +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84" -t_srs EPSG:4258 in.tiff out.tiff ?
I use +proj=longlat for Latitude/longitude (gridDefinitionTemplateNumber = 0).

Comment: You need the center point plus the ellipsoid/datum being used. In PROJ.4, it's "ortho." Are you sure it's Orthographic and not a satellite-based projection?

Comment: This topic might help you: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70207/where-did-the-polygons-go-after-projecting-a-map-in-qgis

Comment: yes is a satellite-based projection