# How to eliminate odd horizontal lines in orthographic projection of California with 30° graticules

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

This question is related to, but different from  [Seeking shapefile with borders for both nations AND ALSO US states (and perhaps also Canadian provinces)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/414812) that was closed.  The commenters on the closed question helped me move farther towards completion of this little project.

I'm trying to create a [grey-green orthographic projection map](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Grey%E2%80%93green_orthographic_projections_maps) of California **only**, very much like [this one of Florida only](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Florida_(1861)_orthographic.svg).

I found [this helpful tutorial](https://bnhr.xyz/2018/09/21/create-a-globe-in-QGIS.html) that describes doing so in QGIS for the Philippines based on the shapefile contained in [this World Borders Dataset](http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php).

I'm now using several complimentary datasets to accomplish my goal, including several from [Natural Earth](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/) that @llaves suggested.

But something seems to be wrong with [the graticules dataset](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/physical/ne_10m_graticules_30.zip) that I think may be obvious in the attached images generated by QVIS using 3 datasets:

1. [boundary lines](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces_lines.zip)
2. [countries](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_0_countries.zip)
3. [graticules at 30° increments](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/physical/ne_10m_graticules_30.zip)

[image: orthographic projection with California at center and 30 degree graticules]

It looks to me like the equator and the arctic circle have been projected as both parts of an oval (I see a curved lines where the equator and arctic circle should be) and also horizontal lines (the two odd horizontal lines) in this image whereas there should be no horizontal latitude lines in any orthographic projection.

I tried using graticule datasets from two different sources, but both produced what appears to be exactly the same result.

Why are these horizontal lines present, and how can I eliminate them while keeping the oval latitude lines?

The association with the other question is superficial at best, and is actually unrelated to my question. I'd like to reopen this question for answers, so I've edited it in hopes of accomplishing that.

Comment: Hi, Check if this answer applies to your case: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/307203/133276. The idea was to create a circle in the projection and cut the geometries that cross it.

Comment: Thank you @GabrielDeLuca. That question and its answers are interesting and educational for me, and I appreciate the suggestion, but the problems the OP is trying to solve are much more complex than my problem here. I'm doing nothing more than adding 3 layers, creating a custom projection, changing some layer properties, and exporting an image. Everything is going as expected except for the graticules dataset. :(

Comment: That sounds like exactly the same problems you're encountering.

Comment: Well I'll look again more carefully. I'm new to doing this kind of work so perhaps I've failed to understand it fully. I still think the question could benefit others who are new to GIS, so I'd still like to have it reopened. I suspect I'm not the only GIS-newbie here.

Comment: Hi, the custom projection parameters that were used are necessary for other users to reproduce the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but I ran into the same problem. What helped me was just re-saving the graticule layer in the same projection as the project:

[image]

[image]

Boom, all weird lines gone. Shame qgis isn't smart enough to do it by itself.