# Polygons at edges of orthographic projection

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, polygon, clip, globe

I am trying to make a globe type map with an orthogonal projection (made using a custom projection with the "origin" set to 20,0). The issue is polygons which meet the edge of projection are clipped by it. From some angles this is not such an issue but here Russia has been partially inverted.
[image: Russia (and China) clipped horribly at boundary of orthographic projection]

My workaround would be to open a PDF in Adobe Illustrator and alter the vector paths on that, not ideal. Is there anyway to do this in QGIS?

Comment: Possible duplicate and lots of option to try: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307194/clipping-polygons-to-hemisphere-for-azimuthal-orthographic-projection-using-qgis

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for